# Curve modifier altering wrongly mesh

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I've been using the curve modifier without problem until now. My problem is I'm trying to curve a mesh, it does curve but keep joining/connecting outside faces.

Instead of having a circle hollowed in the middle, I get a circle with flat faces covering the place normally hollowed. And simply using boolean to make hole doesn't work, because those flat faces are supposed to be on the outside of the mesh that I try to bent. So deleting/cutting them makes big holes and deformation to my mesh.

Picture on the left is the mesh, on the right what I get after curving with bezier circle. (front and top view)

Here are my files: [image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: @Chris I've added them :)

Comment: thanks for the blend file. i added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for that is the bad topology of that object. As you can see it has too less vertical loop cuts so that it can bend.

[image]

Here an example: I took a default cube without any subdivisions, made it a bit flatter and tried to curve it:

It works only, if you have enough subdivision on that axis, on which you want to bend it:

[image]

Comment: Nice illustration :)

Comment: Thank you ‼️❣️